# command with no mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

how could I make a command work without mentioning a user, just by putting that user's nickname on the server?

```js
const member =
 message.mentions.members.first() ||
 message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
 message.member;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Collection#find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find):

```js
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.username === args[0]);
```

Comment: note that the asker specified *nickname* so in this case we'll want `member.nickname === args[0]`

Comment: oh is that what he meant by that! That should be clearer.

Comment: @Klaycon `member.nickname` would work, but `member.displayName` would be better. `member.nickname` will return undefined if the member has no nickname, while `member.displayName` would default to their username if that was the case.

Comment: @Lioness100 good point, I'd agree using the display name would be ideal. Or just checking both, so that users can use one or the other, if for example the nickname is difficult to type.